# install php Zip extension on CentOS 6

Tags: php, opencart, centos6, php-extension

I want to run opencart in VPS server which i bought from GoDaddy. During installation of opencart, opencart give error that Zip extension is disabled. Php 5.5.35 is already installed in server.

I tried installing zip extension with `yum install php-pecl-zip` command and restarted `httpd`, but opencart still asking install of zip extension. `php -m` also does not print zip extension.

How can i install zip extension on CentOS 6 or recompile php with zip extension?

Comment: After you install the extension, you need to add it to php.ini using `extension=zip.so`

Comment: i added extension to php.ini